# Changing contents color of DIV on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have looked for an answer to this but cannot find a simple solution. I want the div, h2 and p to change color when hovering over the parent div gridInner. each has to work independently. Hopefully this can be done.

```
<div class="gridOuter row">
                    <a href="" class="home-block-button">
                    <div class="gridInner first col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <h2>Domain 1</h2>
                        <p>Blurb</p>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="" class="home-block-button">
                        <div class="gridInner col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <h2>Domain 2</h2>
                            <p>Bkurb 2</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="" class="home-block-button">
                        <div class="gridInner last col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <h2>Domain 3</h2>
                            <p>Blurb 3</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

I tried this but it changes all of them. Also the h2 does not change at all. I appreciate any help as this is driving me insane.

```
$('.home-block-button').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find('.gridInner').css({'background-   color':'#302f52'});
    $(this).closest('div').find('.gridInner > h2').css({'color':'#fff'});
});
```

Comment: remove `.closest('div')`. Just keep like this -  `$(this).find('.gridInner').css({'background-color':'#302f52'});` Refer this - https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/Lj3keg0b/2/

Comment: why don't you do it with simple css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this can be done with css also

```
a.home-block-button:hover .gridInner{
  background-color:#302f52;
}
a.home-block-button:hover .gridInner h2{
  color:#fff;
}
```

Still in your case if you want to use js then just write the code like this

```
$( "a.home-block-button" ).hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('.gridInner').css({'background-   color':'#302f52'});
    $(this).find('.gridInner > h2').css({'color':'#fff'});
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.gridInner').css({'background-   color':'initial'});
    $(this).find('.gridInner > h2').css({'color':'initial'});
  }
);
```

At the place of `initial` you can set the values you want on mouse out.

Comment: Thanks I did not know you could change the div contents like that using css. I'd prefer to use css. Many thanks will try this when I get to work tomorrow.